# Counting the rows where a date in one column is before the date in another column (plus additional conditions) in vectorised form (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/joniarroba/noshowappointments) from kaggle with medical appointment data. There is a date that the appointment is made (ScheduledDay) and a date where it is made for (AppointmentDay). There is also patientId and many patients made multiple appointments and whether they turned up or not.

I want to do a cumcount sort of thing with same patients and where they didn't turn up (No-show == 'Yes') but ONLY for no-shows that have already happened by the time the appointment is made.

This is my code for counting the number of booking each patient made and is fine

```
df.sort_values(by='ScheduledDay', inplace=True)

df['book_count'] = df.groupby('PatientId').cumcount()
```

But for my problem I can't work out how to do make it so neat. I have done it but it's not vectorized and needs to loop through the rows. Needless to say it takes ages

```
final_index = df.index.tolist()[-1]

df['miss_count'] = np.NaN
for i in df['ScheduledDay'].iteritems():
    print(f'{final_index} -- {i[0]}')

    patient = df.loc[i[0], 'PatientId']

    count = df.loc[
        (df['AppointmentDay'] < i[1])
        & (df['No-show'] == 'Yes')
        & (df['PatientId'] == patient)].shape[0]

    df.loc[i[0], 'miss_count']  = count

    print(f'\n{count}\n')
```

So in this case I haven't used cumcount because I don't know how to filter for only dates that have happened before

There will then be a column with the count of how many times the patient has made an appointment and not shown up for it before the current making of an appointment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can make use of the pandas [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function, which allows you to run an arbitray function on each row (or column) of a dataframe.

For example:

```
def count_missed_apts_before_now(row, df):
    subdf = df.query("AppointmentDay<@row.ScheduledDay and `No-show`=='Yes' and PatientId==@row.PatientId")
    return len(subdf)
    
missed_apt_counts = df.apply(count_missed_apts_before_now, axis=1, args = (df,))
```

Here, I define a function `count_missed_apts_before_now()` that takes as inputs a single row and the full dataframe. It uses `df.query` to make a smaller df with only no-show rows for the current patient where the AppointmentDay is earlier than the current ScheduledDay value (by "current", I mean the values for the row being processed by the apply function). We can then just count the length of that down-selected dataframe and return it. The `apply` method does that for every row and combines the results into a series.

Note: `apply` is not necessarily fast, though you can compare it to your for loop using `%%timeit` magics.

Also, check whether you need to convert the ScheduledDay timestamps to a pure date, as all the AppointmentDay values seem to be dates only (i.e. all at 00:00 hrs) and in some cases the ScheduledDay has a later timestamp on the same day.

Comment: That's fantastic! I tested it and it takes about 60% of the time of my method and reproduces it exactly. The @row part is something I hadn't learned yet. How does the arguments args=(df, ) work? The arguments are row and df but row isn't specified when calling the function? I can't find anything online to explain how that works

Comment: With `.apply()` the first argument (`row`) is passed automatically (or if you use `axis=0` then the first argument to the function will be the column). So the `args` parameter only needs to pass in any additional positional arguments to the function, and these need to be passed as a tuple i.e. `(df, )`. (The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) also explain how to pass in any keyword args, using `**kwds`)